# Android app get push notification after checking REST API

Tags: java, android, rest, http

I want to check a specific API endpoint, let's say once a day in the background in an Android app, and after I receive information from the API, to send a push notification to the user.

I am quite unexperienced in Android development so I would like to know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check `Work Manager` from Android Jetpack, it easy to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits or the device restarts. Please check from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).